# Background colours are off on sketch cloud's prototype

Tags: sketch-app, prototyping

when trying to use the prototype option on sketch cloud my background, which is white, suddenly becomes black. This happens for all my screens. How can I fix this?
(This black that you see in the picture is meant to be white)
Thanks,

[image]